# Point charges in a sphere

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

If we put N point charges (with charge +q) in a sphere with radius R and the charges can move freely in the sphere but can't get out of it, where will the charges go to and what will be the electrostatic energy in the cases that N=2,3,4?

I thought that the charges would go to the surface of the sphere, but I don't really know why.

Also for N=5 there are two configurations of where the charges will go, which one will have the lowest energy (without calculating this)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The charges will tend to be as far from each other as possible as this would minimize the energy of the system
$$
U = \sum_{ij} \frac{q_i q_j}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r_{ij}}
$$
So you call understand their tendency to go to the surface, for the same reason that if there was no sphere they would fly off to infinity.

For $N$ charges on the sphere, this becomes the old Thompson problem. For $5$ it is visually challenging but recently shown to be a triangular dipyramid, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem

Comment: Is U the energy and how do you derive this?

Comment: yes, the electrostatic potential energy

Comment: But how do you come to this result?

Comment: this is just the textbook result of potential energy between charged point particles, which is equivalent to coulombs law. Remember the force is the gradient of the potential energy